# Minimum spec for stellio-context-broker docker image?

Tags: fiware, fiware-stellio

What would you recommend as minimum ubuntu, OSX and windows platform specs for using the stellio-context-broker docker image?

https://github.com/stellio-hub/stellio-context-broker

Answer (score 0):

For a standard deployment, we typically run Stellio on a VM with 16Gb of RAM and 4 CPU cores. The disk space will of course depend on the quantity of data you'll inject into Stellio (we have long running VMs with frequent but small updates (sensors measures for instance) that use between 20 and 60Gb of disk space).

If you have specific needs (e.g., injecting large amount of data or doing a lot of complex queries), you may need to increase the RAM (especially for the databases that use it a lot to improve performance).

It also runs fine on my laptop (MacBook Pro with 16Gb RAM and quad core i7).